# Link combobox to textboxt in excel vba - error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I tested the following code in Excel 2016. But I encounter an

> error message of 1004

and the code does not work. 
Error line: 
`Me.TextBox1.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox1.Value, xRg, 2, False))`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
Dim xRg As Range
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Set xRg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B8")
Me.ComboBox1.List = xRg.Columns(1).Value
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Me.TextBox1.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox1.Value, 
xRg, 2, False)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `xRg` is declared outside of the scope of the `ComboBox1_Change` event. Thus, the `Combobox1_Change()` does not access it. Try to declare it within:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B8")
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox1.Value, _
                                                        xRg, 2, False)
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't even spot that, i blame being mobile for my commute

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor - I hope you are in a bus/train and not driving :)

Comment: Of course, train to London for a hackathon, a spot of SO to engage my brain before I go tackle some Machine Learning

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor - that's nice, have fun at the hackathon

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Vityata [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52603608/6387479), you will need to assign the xRg variable within your current code block as it has no reference to it.

As an addition to that though, I would advise ditching the vlookup application function in place of assignment by the combobox index: `Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex` and use that as the reference for the row in xRg:

```
Me.TextBox1.Value = xRg.Cells(Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1, 2).Value
```

The ComboBox.ListIndex property is a 0 based array so I have added 1 on to get the proper row assignment.